# GROUP BY clause in SQL

Tags: sql

```
Year    Brand   Amount
2018    Apple   45000
2019    Apple   35000
2020    Apple   75000
2018    Samsung 15000
2019    Samsung 20000
2020    Samsung 95000
2018    Nokia   21000
2019    Nokia   17000
2020    Nokia   14000
```

i want the expexted output to be like:

```
Year     Brand       Amount
2018     Apple       45000
2019     Apple       35000
2020     Samsung     95000
```

THIS IS WHAT I TRIED:

```
Select Year, Brand, Max(Amount)as HighestPrice
from Practice
Group by Year
```

but it shows error:

> "Column 'Practice.Brand' is invalid in the select list because it is
> not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I would highly appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you for each year want the best selling brand? No, the most expensive something?

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because you need both in the group by.  I would just write a standard select and join into the max amount in a sub query and correlate on year.

```
SELECT  YEAR
      ,BRAND
      ,Amount AS HighestPrice
  FROM Practice B
  WHERE Amount = (SELECT MAX(Amount) FROM Practice A
                                    WHERE A.YEAR = B.YEAR) 

 ORDER BY YEAR ASC
```

Comment: Yep, good to go now

Answer (score 1):

A generic SQL version would be:

```
select p.Year, p.Brand, p.Amount as HighestPrice
from Practice p
  join (
    select Year, max(Amount) as Amount
    from Practice
    group by Year
  ) as m on m.Amount=p.Amount
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use partition, example in ssms:

```
SELECT Year, Brand, Amount as HighestPrice
FROM(
  SELECT
  Year, Brand, Amount,
   RANK()OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY Amount DESC) AS rn
  FROM Practice
  ) a
WHERE rn = 1 
ORDER BY year
```

Comment: you might want to consider using rank() in case of a tie.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which database you are using, so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL. You can use `DISTINCT ON` to get the row with the max amount per year.

For example:

```
select distinct on (year) * from practice order by year, amount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use cross apply:

```
select a.year, a.brand, b.amount
from yourtable  a
cross apply (select max(amount) as amount from yourtable
where  a.year = year 
group by year
having max(amount) =a.amount
order by amount desc)b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
https://dbfiddle.uk/Cr6kFqaE

```
select XX.Year,Table1.Brand ,XX.Amount from 
(
   select Year, Max(Amount) as Amount from Table1 group by Year 
)as  XX
left outer join Table1 on Table1.Year= XX.Year and Table1.Amount = XX.Amount
```

Comment: Instead of providing a code only answer, your answer can be made better by providing some explanation to the code, such as why you have used certain techniques